# Use of 64-bit types?

Tags: c++, 64-bit, hash, int64

I am writing some hash functions for a compiler and I use the `__int64` datatype frequently. The compiler is intended to be supported (and so far is) on different OS's. I know that `__int64` is a type that can be compiled by most major C++ compilers for my target systems so that's not the problem. I am using hash functions to make large character strings smaller and quicker to compare and they work wonders on 64-bit capable OS's; but would there be a large enough performance decrease on 32 bit OS's to cancel out the benefits? I could use 32 bit integers but then it would greatly lessen the effectiveness of the hash functions.

Edit:
It is custom code and very simple. The first hash function generates a unique 64-bit int from 12 alphanumeric (including underscore) characters. Then a class handles hashes over 12 characters by creating address-linked lists of 64bit hashes and overloads the comparison operators. The overloaded compares are short circuited and compare down the address-linked list. I've ran tests on my machine to compare speed of randomly generate large hashes (100 - 300 characters) compared to themselves (worst-case senario) and it proved to be faster than string compares. In order to better simulate the overhead of generating hashes, I've also ran compare tests of pre-generated large hashes compares against them selves. This is all running with code optimization turned off. With ~1 billion hash compares vs. ~1 billion string compares, the hash took around 16% of the time. This was all in a 64 environment though. I don't have a 32-bit machine to run tests with

Comment: I guess you don't have access to a 32bit machine to test this on?

Comment: Which hash function? There should be good tuned implementations of all common hash functions for both 32-bit and 64-bit registers in crypto libraries or on google. Or is it something quick and custom? In which case we can't really help you determine the impact: it depends what operations you're doing and how much everything can be kept in registers in the core loop.

Comment: Not so sure if you appreciate how large 4 billion is.  If you make one million dollars a week, it will take you the rest of your life to save up 4 billion.  Counting that, at a dollar bill a second, will take you another 136 years.

Comment: @Hans Passant: 4 billion is not so big. It's the number of cigarettes smoked in China every 16 hours.

Comment: Whether 4 billion is a large number or not depends (as always). For a hash function output, 64 bit is rather small. 4 billion dollars are very much for a single person but not that much for Microsoft. When you juggle statistics every day, it propably doesn't seem much.

Comment: When you have two strings with the same 64-bit hash, do you just assume they're the same string, or do you check to be sure?  In other words, is a hash collision a performance hit or a correctness problem?

Comment: I am going to try and answer all the questions here. It is custom code and very simple. The first hash function generates a unique 64-bit int from 12 alphanumeric (including underscore) characters. Then a class handles hashes over 12 characters by creating address-linked lists and overloads the comparison operators. The overloaded compares are short circuited and compare down the address-linked list. I've ran tests on my machine to compare speed of randomly generate large hashes (100 - 300 characters) compared to themselves (worst-case senario) and it proved to be faster than string compares.

Comment: In order to better simulate the overhead of generating hashes, I've also ran compare tests of pre-generated large hashes compares against them selves. This is all running with code optimization turned off. With ~10 billion hash compares vs. ~10 billion string compares, the hash took around 16% of the time. This was all in a 64 environment though. I don't have a 32-bit machine to run tests with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

64bit sized integers aren't substantially slower at all on a 32bit x86 architecture. They're not as fast as 32bit ints, obviously, but aren't notably slower. It's not at all reckless to use a 64bit int for hashes regardless of x86 or x64. The additional overhead will likely be minimal compared to say, a couple of unneeded dynamic allocations or failed algorithms.

Comment: I take your point that the time needed for the integer operations will probably be dominated by all the other shit that needs to be done. But the integer operations themselves will be significantly slower -- perhaps 10-20 times slower, depending on how the compiler organises the operands into registers. If hash table performance is an important issue, then the OP should certainly run some tests.

Comment: That does make a lot of sense. I guess I should concentrate more on optimizing other parts instead of just the hashing stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that comparing four 32-bit variables will be faster than comparing two 64-bit variables, since I guess the compiler will generate the fastest code: if your processor doesn't support 64-bit operations, your compiler will generate code that compares it in two steps, just like you would do by hand.
This of course depends on your compiler.

---

Anyway, there are other tools that will make your comparisons even faster, but which are not available everywhere, for example vectorial operations (provided by SSE extensions) that allow to compare even 8*4 bytes at once.

If you need to optimize your code as much as possible I'd suggest you to add some preprocessor directives in order to enable optimizations only when the system supports them.

Comment: I did some research today on how 64-bit arithmetic is emulated in a 32-bit environment and it seems like it would take significantly longer. However I think that string compares of equal use would still be a lot slower. It's unlikely some one is going to write code that requires millions or even thousands of hashes anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it would greatly lessen the effectiveness of the hash function? Have you run tests? Certainly 64 bits is a better hash than 32 bits if (i) the number of items hashed is significantly more than 2^16 and (ii) computing the 64-bit hash is cheap. Which of (i) or (ii) (or both) is true in your case? If performance is important, you might want to use different hash functions depending on the underlying operating system. Otherwise, I would say: write a 32-bit version, and a 64-bit version; try them both out on a 64-bit system, and a 32-bit system; and you'll see whether it's worth busting a gut over.

Answer (score 0):

All hash function that I've used return the value in an array of bytes (uchar) to avoid your problem.